# Can't convert interface to concrete interface

Tags: c#

Why i can't convert implementation of interface which concrete implement generic interface? I need for Cat, Dog etc own interface realisation.

```
public interface IMarker { }
public class ResultA : IMarker
{
}
public class ResultB : IMarker
{ }

public interface IService<T> where T : IMarker
{
    public List<T> DoStuff();
}

public interface ICatService : IService<ResultA>
{ }
public interface IDogService : IService<ResultB>
{ }

public class CatService : ICatService
{
    public List<ResultA> DoStuff()
    {
        return new List<ResultA>();
    }
}

public class DogService : IDogService
{
    public List<ResultB> DoStuff()
    {
        return new List<ResultB>();
    }
}

public abstract class Animal
{
    protected readonly IService<IMarker> _svc;

    protected Animal(IService<IMarker> svc)
    {
        _svc = svc;
    }
}
public class Cat : Animal
{
    public Cat(ICatService svc) : base(svc)
    {
    }
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    public Dog(ICatService svc) : base(svc)
    {
    }
}
```

> CS1503    Argument 2: cannot convert from 'ICatService' to 'IService'

I have DI for services i.e. :

```cs
services.AddTransient<ICatService, CatService>();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for such behaviour is that in general case `IService<ResultA>` is not `IService<IMarker>` (basically I would argue the same because C# classes do not support variance, for pretty good reason - see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/246101/2501279) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588183/why-animals-animals-new-cat5-compiles-but-listanimal-animals-new-list)).

In this concrete case everything can be fixed by making the interface [covariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-generic-interfaces) and leveraging the covariance of `IEnumerable<T>`:

```cs
public interface IService<out T> where T : IMarker
{
    public IEnumerable<T> DoStuff();
}

public class CatService : ICatService
{
    public IEnumerable<ResultA> DoStuff() => return new List<ResultA>();
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
    public Cat(CatService svc) : base(svc)
    {
    }
}
```

But not sure that in your actual code you will be able to.

Or just make the base class generic (if this suits your use case):

```cs
public abstract class Animal<T> where T : IMarker
{
    protected readonly IService<T> _svc;

    protected Animal(IService<T> svc)
    {
        _svc = svc;
    }
}
```

**Original answer**

`CatService` does not implement `ICatService`, i.e. the fact that `ICatService` inherits only `IService<ResultA>` does not mean that they are the same, [C# is strongly-typed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/) (mostly :-) language and compiler will consider those two interfaces being different ones (though related). You need either to make `CatService` to implement `ICatService`:

```cs
public class CatService : ICatService
{
    // ...
}
```

Or register and resolve the `IService<ResultA>` interface (basically skipping intermediate interface at all):

```cs
services.AddTransient<IService<ResultA>, CatService>();

// ...

public Cat(IService<ResultA> svc) : base(svc){}
```

Comment: Sorry for confusing, in fact I meant that: CatService  implements ICatService which implements IService<ResultA>. And in this case I get this error.

Comment: @TryHard what is `base(svc)`? What is the base class for `Cat`?

Comment: @TryHard see the update (this was actually discussed in your previous question in the second answer)

Comment: please could you check code now, i fixed it now it doesn't work ). I saw there was bad example.

Comment: @TryHard yep, I've already reconstructed your code an error and reflected it in the aforementioned update.